# Selecting dynamically generated element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<c:forEach items="${ sample }" var="test">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>${ test.test }.</strong></td> // I want to get the text
        <td>
            <fieldset class="span11">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label"><strong>${ test.blah }</strong></label>
                    <div class="controls" id="question${ test.blah }">
                        <c:forEach var="beng" items="${ anotherSample }">
                            <form:radiobutton path="boom" class="question-choices" data-label="${ choices }" value="${ beng-boom }"/><br>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>                 
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to get the text from the first `<td>` from the `radio button`:

What I tried so far is:

```
$('.question-choices').on('change', function() {
    console.log( $(this).parent('tr').closest('td').text() );
});
```

But this returns empty string

Comment: Because the parent is a div, not a tr. Read the docs for more information. http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @epascarello `parents('tr')` seems to do what OP wants. Could be a typo.

Comment: `parents()` is a bad choice.

Comment: @epascarello is there a reason to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this;

```
$('.question-choices').on('change', function() {
    console.log( $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').find("strong").html() );
});
```

Comment: I want the readability of this but this also includes the `<strong>` tag

Comment: Is there a reason why did you use `.find("strong").html()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: I prefer to use html() in this case to get all content @newbie

Answer (score 1):

`parent()` only gets a **direct** parent.

Try using `.parents`:

```
$('.question-choices').on('change', function() {
    console.log( $(this).parents('tr').closest('td').text() );
});
```

Comment: parents() would give you multiple elements if nested tables. This is also broken because .closest('td') would be looking at the TR's parents!